# Getting only time from Python parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, datetime

Using ArcGIS 10.4, how I can modify the `Date()` functions on VB or Python scripts of field Calculator

```
Now (  )
datetime.datetime.now( )
```

to get only time like

> 12:32

Comment: datetime.datetime.now() should return a datetime object with the date and time.. are you trying to store this in a date field or a string field? What do you get if you calc to datetime.datetime.now().date()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little off topic as it has to do with pure python (or VB).

Using the python parser you can get the current time with the function:

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M') # use '%h:%M' for 12 hour time
```

Have a read of [strftime behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), note that this will be a string, not a datetime, so can only be stored in a string field.

Answer (score 2):

The following python code can be run in a field calculate:

```py
t = datetime.datetime.now()
h = t.hour
m = t.minute
s = str(h) + ":" + str(m)
```

You would then return the string `s` which would be something "23:51".

You should also explore the tool [Convert Time Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/convert-time-field.htm) which already exists and can extract out a variety of formatted date/times. It is in the same toolbox as the Calculate Field tool...